Why some files are not visible for 'Get-FileHash' in PowerShell?
I have a similar problem to the one mentioned in Windows PowerShell: Get-FileHash and long file paths ,
generating the same error but it is not connected to path length as is there. With code:
Get-ChildItem G:\Path\to\Any\_Directory -Filter *.* -Recurse -File | % { ($_.Mode,$_.FullName, $_.LastWriteTime, $_.Length, (Get-FileHash $_ -Algorithm MD5).Hash) -join ";"} > F:\FILES_MD5_HASH.txt

it is calculating the hash for some files or gives the same error:
' because it does not exist.
At C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.psm1:11
0 char:36
+                 $pathsToProcess += Resolve-Path $Path | Foreach-Objec ...
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound:

It does not depend on path length. If I take a path for any file with an error powershell will calculate only for this one file md5 hash without error. Always the same files are causing this error, various types, sizes, modification time etc. Even files in the same directory and the same file name pattern (eg 20240108_124523.jpg) as 'successful' have problems. Any idea why some files are not visible for the file Hash md5 method? I think if that problem will be solved it will help with the problem. My working theory for this is that my HDD is too slow for this algorithm or problems with disk cache. I'm using Windows 11 Pro, so it is not connected with OS version. My directory contains more than 9k files and subfolders, all data size is 338GB, and the longest file path has 207 chars, but the problem occurs without any correlation to this length. The abovementioned code will calculate hash for let's say 150 files from 9k which I have, always missing the same files.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Start by trying: replacing $_ with a property like $_.FullName. Then try providing -Path parameter explicitly, it's always more trustable in PowerShell. If it doesn't work, include examples of paths that don't work in the question.
